# Can't get capistrano 3 to deploy from bitbucket to bluehost

Tags: wordpress, git, capistrano3

I'm trying to use Capistrano 3 to deploy my wordpress site which is hosted on bluehost and the origin repo is on bitbucket.

I've been using this [(wp-deploy)](https://github.com/Mixd/wp-deploy) vanilla template as I don't really understand ruby or Capistrano enough to know how to roll my own solution.

I've got ssh-keys for my local machine and for my server to allow password less key logins from my local machine to bluehost server and from my bluehost server to bitbucket repo.

In running this command as suggested.

```
bundle exec cap staging deploy
```

The only output I get is

```
INFO [99aeea5e] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/sansgil.com/ on sansgil.com
 INFO [99aeea5e] Finished in 4.748 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO Uploading /tmp/sansgil.com/git-ssh.sh 100.0%
 INFO [d1a7fd83] Running /usr/bin/env chmod +x /tmp/sansgil.com/git-ssh.sh on sansgil.com
 INFO [d1a7fd83] Finished in 2.570 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO [02cfd0ab] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/sansgil.com/ on sansgil.com
 INFO [02cfd0ab] Finished in 2.666 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO Uploading /tmp/sansgil.com/git-ssh.sh 100.0%
 INFO [456588e4] Running /usr/bin/env chmod +x /tmp/sansgil.com/git-ssh.sh on sansgil.com
 INFO [456588e4] Finished in 2.535 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
```

And looking inside the git-ssh.sh script is this code.

```
#!/bin/sh -e
exec /usr/bin/ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "$@"
```

The deploy_to dirs on my bluehost server have nothing in them. It would appear that Capistrano isn't deploying any sites via git.

I need help as I don't know why Capistrano isn't deploying the wordpress repo?

Comment: Instead of running your deploy in `:info` mode please use `:debug` mode and paste the results here or in a pastebin.

Comment: Thank you so much @cfx. I'd given up on this but changing that bit of code seems to have helped make some progress.

First off the git repo URL for my bitbucket repo was wrong which was causing an error. Then secondly the /tmp dir doesn't allow executables on Bluehost so I changed that to run from ~/tmp which now get's me a lot further in the whole process and I'm seeing Cap upload files to the server now.

I am still stumbling on a new error though that cap can't clone into the wp submodule for some reason even though the git URL looks correct to me. 

http://pastebin.com/QNhbifpK

Comment: Can you post your entire `deploy.rb` file please? I just posted about this but using a different setup here in case you want to try it: http://cfxdesign.com/deploy-wordpress-with-capistrano-on-bluehost/ but I used WP as a Composer dependency. The problem you're having is that Bluehost won't use the `git://` protocol afaik so you need to clone over `https://`.

Comment: @cfx I've actually moved to a new web host/dreamhost. And seem to be coming up against a new set of errors. Mainly that capistrano/git wont recognise the git checkout -B flag when run from my local machine via cap to the remote server. However when I run git checkout -B via SSH on the remote server it runs fine.

Would you be able to shed some light on the situation?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25171053/capistrano-git-not-recognising-checkout-b-flag-unless-logged-in-via-ssh